# Dedicated bike GPS computer over smartphone

Tags: bike-computer, smartphone-mount

Yes, I know it's a duplicate of questions that have been asked before, for example this one: [Are there advantages of dedicated bike computer instead of smartphone apps?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/are-there-advantages-of-dedicated-bike-computer-instead-of-smartphone-apps)

But I feel that most of the reasons given 8 years ago in response to this question have been invalidated:

- The phone is larger → yes, but you still have to have it with you
- glare → max screen brightness has improved a lot in recent years
- not designed to sit out exposed to hot sun, extreme temps, and rain → not really true any longer, with the arrival of IP67/68 resistant phones
- ease of use → new phone apps like Komoot, Strava, MapMyRide, etc. make the phones seriously better for bicycling than 8 years ago
- battery life → much improved, with a new iPhone I'm getting at least 6 hours of use on the bike, and that's *with* the Komoot navigation on; for longer rides, it's easy to pack small power banks.

So my question to anyone who is still using and paying for specialized bicycle computers like Garmin and Wahoo, in 2019, what are you getting out of them that a contemporary smartphone doesn't give you?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94795/discussion-on-question-by-ttarchala-dedicated-bike-gps-computer-over-smartphone).   Every of those 23 comments was chat or replies, none were comments to improve or clarify the question.  Please make your answers as answers.

Comment: Maybe consider proper fitness heart rate monitors to your question; something like the polar m400*, a mid ranged, fully fledged heart rate monitor is durable, IP rated, tracks all sorts of metrics, connects to all sorts of apps and a strap that will fit most arms and bicycle bars, IMO is still a better option than specialized bike computers and cellphones for someone who's not a pro**. *Not affiliated with polar, worked in fitness industry and cycled for many, many years.
**A cheap Cateye that measures speed and distance can be useful as a supplementary tracker.

Comment: @BossRoss that's not a comment, that's an answer.  Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I used a phone for about two months, then bought a Wahoo GPS computer in March 2018.
The primary motivation was that

- **My phone has lousy GPS** (Huawei P10).  Multiple times a week, it would claim that I'd teleported half way across town, lose signal and never get it back, or drift so that the track would look continuous but end up hundreds of meters from my destination.  I hear that iPhones have pretty good GPS.  My Wahoo has near-perfect GPS; the worst it does is beep at me in forests on cloudy days because it thinks I've wandered too far off the side of the road.  Some speed sensors can talk to phones by Bluetooth, which may improve phone (and cycle computer) tracking accuracy.

Other advantages:

- **Size and mounting**. My phone isn't big, but it's much bigger than my Wahoo and I found it somewhat inconvenient on my handlebars.
- **Battery life**.  My Wahoo claims 15hrs. I probably get more like twelve, but that means I only need to recharge it about once a week.  Six hours of battery life would mean that, if I set out on a 4.5hr ride without having my phone fully charged and things took longer than I was expecting, I could easily be caught an hour away from home with no GPS and no way to call for help.  Which is to say...
- **Redundancy**. Having a cycle computer and a phone means that I have one device to keep me safely on the right track and a separate device that will give me backup navigation and, in the worst case get me help.
- **User interface**.  The Wahoo has six buttons. While I'm riding, I can press the buttons to get to the screen I want without looking, and then glance at the computer to find out what I need to know. Touch-screen navigation of the phone requires you to look at it and is awkward when things are bumping around. I put the phone inside a waterproof pouch (because, England) but found that made the touch screen awkward to use.  Touch screens are a pain with gloves, too.
- **Crash resistance**.  The one time I've crashed, my Wahoo (and my knees and shoulder) got scuffed up against the concrete in a way that I'm pretty sure would have wrecked my phone, but which caused only cosmetic damage to the Wahoo.  My phone was in my jersey pocket and was completely undamaged and available for use if I'd needed to take photographs or call an ambulance, or a friend or taxi to get me home. Of course, one can easily imagine  a crash in which the contents of one's jersey pocket get trashed, while stuff mounted on the handlebars survives. On the other hand, the phone felt much less secure on the handlebar than the Wahoo does.

In other words, not much has actually changed.  The only thing I've not mentioned that came up a lot in the previous thread was screen brightness.  I guess my phone's screen brightness would probably be fine, but it was kind of moot, as I never did figure out how to stop it blanking the screen after a few minutes of riding.  I'm not sure how my phone would have coped with being in its waterproof pouch on a really hot day; I only used it in the English winter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94806/discussion-on-answer-by-david-richerby-dedicated-bike-gps-computer-over-smartpho).

Answer (score 17):

I use a phone for navigating long rides (up to 400km/20 hours). I'm rare among distance riders, and if I had unlimited money might get a dedicated unit. For me the phone works well - a dynamo keeps the battery topped up, I've got offline mapping and setting the screen brightness manually means I'm not dazzled. I don't (usually) have turn by turn navigation, but following a line on a map suits me and I can import gpx files.

So why would I use a dedicated GPS?

- The biggest issue is touchscreens and rain. My phone is fully waterproof but heavy rain makes the screen unreliable (big drops detected as touches, for example). I've made a little windscreen that helps a lot while moving forwards, but doesn't do much in stop-start conditions.
- Having the phone as backup navigation would be nice - I probably carry more weight/bulk in maps/route sheets than a basic GPS unit (some form of backup is essential for what I ride).
- Occasional all-night rides do require an external battery (9pm start in winter, riding 340km through the night and the whole of the next day) as my dynamo runs my lights after dark. That would also be the case on a GPS, and some of those don't like to charge while riding.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisH for the detailed answer. "heavy rain makes the screen unreliable" --> isn't this a very temporary problem by nature? Heavy rain rarely lasts very long. There are also fully enclosed phone holders/bags, e.g. a Topeak DryBag, I have one and rain drops are not a problem, however the sensitivity of touch input recognition goes down too.

Comment: @ttarchala The windshield I made was prompted by [a 17 hour ride](https://www.strava.com/activities/1906047502) with one or two brief breaks from the rain (and none from the headwind).  Navigating through towns was hard when the screen zoomed by itself but wouldn't recognise me zooming back. I've [answered](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/58217/7309) about the merits of waterproof bags rather than naked phones - summary: a waterproof phone wins every time for me (the bag fogs up).

Comment: Curious that the bag can fog up, I never had this problem, considering that the phone itself heats it up from the inside. About the zooming, again a better navigation app might solve that; I'm not paid by Komoot by anything but this app does a nifty trick where it zooms in before a turn and then zooms back out after, automatically. The problem I have with the Topeak bag is that I have to mash pretty hard on the screen, through the thick foil, for my input to be recognised, and even then, it can be mis-recognised.

Comment: @ttarchala if I get a few drops of water inside, such as while putting the phone in, the heat from the phone evaporates the water which then condenses on the inside of the clear plastic. I must admit I've never tried it when I've been able to put it in completely dry - no shelter or the phone already wet. Auto zoom can only possibly work with turn by turn navigation, and I haven't found an app that does that nicely, completely offline, while showing me exactly what I want; in comparison following a line on a map is easy, but the phone doesn't know a turn is coming up.

Comment: BTW [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/UK-Motorcycle-Bike-Motorbike-Handlebar-Phone-Holder-GPS-Mount-For-iphone-Samsung-/382980150282?var=&hash=item592b65540a) is the mount I now use after breaking too many plastic ones

Comment: I actually broke the metal mount as well - not in a crash but a few hours before one

Comment: Ebay link is now broken - a photo should be more enduring, can you snap one at some point?

Comment: @Criggie I noticed that.  And with that one broken too (a few hours before my bad crash 2 years ago) I can neither take pictures nor recommend it.  Some of the metal ones still have a really flimsy bit in them.  My current one is so heavily modified it's not worth showing

Answer (score 14):

Main reason not to use you phone has to be cost and crash resistance. While a dedicated unit may set you back $250-$350, many people have a decent phone with a replacement cost of over $1000. Given the number of phones I see with broken screens, the crash resistance of a phone has to be considered less than ideal at best. A dedicated unit is not only significantly cheaper, but also far more crash resistant.

For someone who Mountain bikes, a phone on the bike is going to work out more expensive than a dedicated unit. For many the risk of crashing is low enough its an option.

Comment: In my experience with crashes, in a typical crash the bike hits the ground with one of the handlebar ends first, and the phone is additionally protected in its mount/case too. I have never seen or heard of a phone cracked in a bike crash - have you, or anybody? It would have to be a pretty unlucky crash for the phone to take the brunt of the impact. Crash resistance of phones has also improved a lot in recent years.

Comment: The initial impact may well be on the bar-end but that's by no means the end of the crash. Crashes can break bones, so they can certainly break phone mounts. Once your phone is free of the bike, who knows where it will land and what will land on top of it. I don't know people who cycle with a phone on the handlebars so the fact that I don't know of anyone breaking a phone that way doesn't say anything.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Cycling with the phone mounted to the handlebars is certainly getting more popular. I was in a 3000 riders gran fondo-type event recently, and observed that perhaps 1 in 10 riders had this kind of setup.

Comment: Yes, it is popular, but on black downhill and trail MTB trails I have yet to see one bar mounted phone.  On green XC trails have seen one or two (on bikes that were clearly not going to be used on the blue runs)

Comment: I tried mounting my phone to my handlebar. It lasted all of 30 seconds. It was just so obviously unreliable that I wasn't out of my parking lot before I got rid of the mount and put the phone in a bag on the top tube. I don't know how people do it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Out of curiosity, which mount/case did you try? Personally I've had the Topeak mount, with several cases for several iPhone generations, for the last 7 years, and it never once failed me (in terms of losing the smartphone), it is quite obviously _reliable_ from the get go. I've heard good things about the Quadlock system too. But indeed I've seen some mounts - mostly in the bicycle sections of supermarkets - into which I would definitely hesitate to put a €1000 phone.

Comment: Possibly stupid question, but why would you have handlebar mounted phone on black downhill trail? Is it too difficult to navigate without GPS or too boring to survive without checking social media?

Comment: @ttarchala In retrospect, not spending enough money was most likely the cause of the problem. But I use $100 phones, not $1000 phones...

Comment: Also on cost if you get a new phone every 2 years that's a new shape and needs a new mount and you're buying fancy high quality mounts that run 50-80USD compared to lifecycle of $250 dedicated computer....

Comment: Hi @Affe, the last RideCase I bought for the iPhone 6 in 2014 still fits the relatively new iPhone 8, with which I intend to ride at least until the next year's iPhone… and it's pretty sturdy, it doubles as a regular phone case too.

Comment: @ojs - How else will you take selfies while mid jump?

Comment: During this year's MS-150 I was following a fellow who hit a rumble strip. His phone was jarred out of its mount and hit the pavement. I found myself following him later in the day and learned that his phone case had done its job; the phone was fine. But don't count on being this lucky.

Comment: @mattnz dedicated bike camera like GoPro, of course :)

Comment: I know this is old, but w.r.t. MTB trails: I use a bar-mounted rugged phone on bridleways, blues and occasional reds, including some (very small) jumps - I've only got a hardtail after all (or a tourer which I have used on the local blue trail).  Sometimes I need the navigation for XC rides, more often to navigate  the ride to the trails, and I don't take it off when I get there.  My current phone has a lanyard that I clip on to the bars as well.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to all the other advantages a dedicated cycling computer has over a phone, battery life when collecting data from wireless sensors such as speed and cadence sensors and power meters is much better with a cycling-specific computer compared to a smart phone.

ANT+ is designed for low power consumption, so battery life for ANT+ components is much better.  And that longer battery life doesn't only apply to the dedicated cycling computer - it applies to the sensors, too.  I've had to replace the battery on my ANT+-only SRM power meter only twice in the 8 **years** I've had it.  I've had to replace the battery on my PowerTap C1 crankset that transmits both Bluetooth and ANT+ three times already in the six months I've owned it.  And I'm not riding anywhere near as much as I was when I first got that SRM.  Back then I was averaging 50-60 hours per month.  Now I'm at more like 20-30.

Another benefit that I haven't noted mentioned yet - try using your touch-screen phone while wearing heavy gloves or even mittens because it's -5C.  A touch-screen cycling computer is designed to handle gloves and even mittens just fine.  Nor does a cycling computer go crazy from misinterpreting rain drops as "touches".

As a cycling computer, a phone makes a pretty good phone.  For a lot of reasons.

All the mental gymnastics in the universe can't make a general-purpose device that has to have a relatively fragile and large screen work as well as a device dedicated for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for reminding us about the below-zero scenario and the ANT+ battery advantage. In your experience, in low temperatures, do the dedicated cycling computers lose less battery capacity than smartphones?

Comment: About the "mental gymnastics", honestly, I'm not trying to engage in advocacy. The reason I asked the question is that I've been so happy riding with smartphones for the last few years that I seriously started wondering why would anyone do anything else. I talked to some friends with Garmins and their answers were, mostly, for historical reasons - they had accumulated a lot of Garmin compatible equipment or they were on the Garmin site/social network etc. So I asked the question here.

Comment: +1 - ANT+ is awesome - and most android phones have it already.  The exceptions being really old ones and very cut-price bottom models.    No Apple phone has ANT+, so you'd need a head unit that can act as a bridge/translator.

Comment: +1 for mentioning riding in winter. My edge 520 had no problem this winter with -20C but the screen of my phone became unusable

Answer (score 7):

My old GPS was powered by AA batteries. No need for recharging in the field (powerbank or so), you can just take a sealed pair of alkaline batteries with you so if something unforseen happens, the trip takes much longer than expected, you have at any rate still backup power to navigate. Even if you'd forgotten those, you could easily get fitting batteries at any supermarket or gas station and can immediately continue with navigation.

(The batteries I was actually using *normally* were NiMH, and I recharge those.)

Well, that old Garmin eTrex broke last year, and I then got a more modern, powerful, and internal-lithium powered one. The new one is better in most regards, but I am rather more anxious about battery life now than I used to be.

For another thing: I personally reject phones out of principle. Google, Apple or anybody else has no business knowing where I go with my bike.
Clearly, this doesn't bother 98% of other people though, so...

Comment: All location data sent to Apple's servers is anonymized by a unique generated identifier which is not tied to the AppleID or to the device. I don't know about Google, but if you want to be worried about anybody when using phones, smart or not, then worry about your local GSM provider which knows your approximate location at all times. Anyway, for the 98% of the sheep that we are, being powered by alkaline batteries is hardly any advantage.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvote is for, I thought your answer was useful because you brought up a point that nobody else made.  I occasionally use a hiking GPS as a bicycling computer because two AAs will easily make it through a long day, and I can easily take spare batteries also.

Comment: The downvote is from me. While the point about the BIG BROTHER WATCHING YOU is indeed unique, pointing to alkaline batteries as an advantage is clearly absurd. Weight-wise, convenience-wise or ecology-wise, power banks are the superior solution.

Comment: @ttarchala Apple uses closed-source software. How could you possibly know there's no backdoor, perhaps one mandated by US government agencies? – Anyways, that was only a side note. As I said, I'm well aware that you and most other people won't care about this.

Comment: As for the batteries: maybe I should have clarified: the normal batteries I use are NiMH, which are easily recharged. The point is that I can have the backup primaries, which I don't need to worry about ever (expect perhaps check the best-before every year or so). With a power bank, it's another device that needs to be charged, a connection cable to pack and unpack (which I may forget), etc..

Comment: @leftaroundabout  People have been running wireshark (or compatible) on iPhones' traffic since forever. While it's still possible that there could be some steganographic snooping, it's unlikely in the experts' opinion. And it's not that we don't care; it's about picking our battles.

Comment: I'm not saying that cell batteries are _generally_ better – for a laptop or indeed phone, which are _normally_ operated close to wall sockets, built-in lithium batteries are certainly superior. But for an outdoor device, it's different.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Why are NiMH batteries superior for the outdoors? To my knowledge, they have worse energy density and they lose charge faster. From the convenience point of view, I always have a few power banks that I keep charged. When I intend to go on a long bicycle ride, I just pack one of them plus a short Lightning cable.

Comment: @ttarchala they do have a lower energy density than Li-ion, but given the GPS' low energy consumption this isn't really a problem (the weight, even including backups, is almost neglectable). The types I'm using are low-self-discharge ones and can be kept on shelf for multiple months, I think significantly better than Li-Ion in that regard. — Good for you if you have a few power banks that you keep charged. It's still one more thing you need to think of.

Comment: ...furthermore, the batteries are also compatible with my headlight. Although, for the lights I think I _will_ switch to Li-Ion at some point, because of the energy density.

Comment: Anyway, my question was about contemporary smartphones vs. buying a specialised bicycle GPS computer. If you look at the range of available GPS computers in 2019, can you find any powered by alkaline batteries? From Wahoo and Garmin, the two most popular brands, I think there are currently none on sale.

Comment: @ttarchala it's the Garmin eTrex series, which is still available.

Comment: "Good for you if you have a few power banks that you keep charged. It's still one more thing you need to think of." - I find it easier to remember keep them charged (they lose typically perhaps ¼ of the charge per 2 months, so it's pretty infrequent) than to remember to buy the alkalines. Also with the power banks, typically they have a light and a button which shows me the charge level. With alkalines you never know. Or worse, it may happen that you mix new ones with partially used ones etc. (in a household with kids who need batteries for their toys, you can never be sure which is which).

Comment: @ttarchala This is not a discussion forum. Please stop trying to engage every answerer in lengthy discussions about every single thing they say.

Answer (score 7):

I work for the world's largest bike parts distributor, and we sell a lot of Garmin equipment. The appeal, especial with Garmin (and what they're pushing) is the device independence and precision. If you buy a Garmin, that device will literally be supported forever, and with quality that meets and exceeds military / naval standards. I have an old Garmin from 1995 meant for surveying, and the software will still work in windows (albeit in compatibility mode). No phone does this. Not even your top of the line Samsung and Iphones.

Now my education is in electrical engineering, so let's allow for room there as well. The GPS on your phone is, at the very best, Half-arsed. It really has to be, as, for example, the Samsung galaxy s9 has the board area equivalent to about 2.5 SD cards, and likely 8-12 layers of copper traces. With all of these traces carrying information, It's *very* difficult to actually read a GPS signal. at the best of days, you'll likely get accuracy with a radius of 2 meters (6.5ft), and that's with a clear shot of the sky. With a dedicated GPS, you  get much more consideration into the GPS itself, and as a result, the accuracy (on the best of days) can get as low as 2 inches, and if you're using some of the fancy tech that the DNR has, 2cm. On the more overcast days, you'll get 2-3 feet.

If you're a data nerd like me, increasing accuracy by such a factor is an amazing benefit, especially if you're off-roading and there's no trails that you can snap your results to. In a road situation, you probably would not need more than a phone. almost anywhere else, it's worth your money. I highly recommend a detachable one, as then you're not limited to just your bicycle.

Comment: Great stuff - thank you for joining SE, and also well done for declaring your connection up-front.  Feel free to have a crack at any other outstanding questions

Comment: Thank you for the answer which really underscores and explains the one unique technical point of the dedicated devices. It's not a big problem for me on the roads, but on a MTB, especially in wooded areas I can frequently observe a momentary GPS drift by up to 10-15 meters. This can cause missed Strava segments... so I understand the appeal to the competitive crowd. Personally though I'm still not convinced that it's worth my money.

Comment: @ttarchala for biking alone, I can agree, but I also do things like geocaching, hiking,  an the like on occasion.

Answer (score 4):

I use a Garmin 510. I keep telling myself that I will retire it for the newer 520 when it breaks but the darn thing won't break.

When I ride, I don't want to be interrupted by life outside of my bike. Yes, I will always keep a phone on me for all rides for emergencies and to send my location to my wife, but it will be on silent and tucked away safely in my back jersey pocket. I turned off all notifications on my Garmin watch as well. This is my time, whatever happens off the bike I will get to when I finish the ride. By the way, that is also the way that I drive too.

- Phone is larger, too large to be put on my handlebars. I have an Note 8 and although I will have it with me, it will be tucked in my jersey pocket.
- Glare is not a problem on my bike computer or my phone due to being a super bright phone but again, it is really big and very breakable.
- My phone gets hot in the sun and yes, it is water proof but not nearly as tough as my GPS Garmin. My Garmin has survived an accident that put me in the hospital for days. At the time I was using my summer phone [Samsung Active] and it was built to be tough but since I gave that one away, I have only a pair of Notes that I use. They aren't known for being all that tough and they are expensive. Would you want to strap a fragile $1000 devise on your handlebar that is so big that it could act as a sail?
- Ease of use. Sorry, doesn't get much easier than my Garmin.
- Battery life. My Garmin will last a 16 hour ride, long after I have given up.

Answer (score 4):

I bought a Wahoo Elemnt a few month for a simple reason: cycling is for me the most demanding use of the phone, having the phone and cycling GPS separated is better on the long run and allows to choose phones that wouldn't be in the options if cycling is in the requirements.

While it is true that navigation apps have gotten better, cycling GPS have also gotten better. The main gripe I had with my old Garmin unit was to copy routes to the device, which isn't a problem anymore. Current devices synchronise routes automatically with popular apps, display notifications and provide the GPS measurements to the phone for live-tracking features. With navigation, I personally don't need more when riding.

Using the phone for cycling basically requires to take a large phone to have a large battery. Also, cycling causes additional wear on the phone battery: first because of the obvious use of the GPS and the display when riding. And also because direct exposure to sun heats up the phone and then the battery: exposure to heat also increases wear on the battery.

Another concern I have if keeping the phone "as long as possible" is linked to waterproofing. After replacing the screen or the battery, the phone can't be considered fully waterproof anymore. If you don't use the phone mounted on the handle bar, it can be stored in a place less exposed to water (waterproof pocket in a bag).

Regarding the choice of the phone, I prefer small phones, that have by design smaller batteries (that would also wear faster in case of heavy use). Given phones are now mature products, I also don't mind having an older model (I don't like the 'jewel' feeling when having a new phone).

To complete my answer with my 'purchase history': my main phone was an iPhone 7 Plus. After purchasing the Wahoo, I replaced the 7+ by a refurbished iPhone SE 2016 (with a new battery). When using Spotify (and live tracking from the GPS), the battery drain on the phone is about 8-10%/hour, and I can leave it plugged to a powerbank in my bag if needed. While there are some drawbacks (photos — size is for me a trade-off, not a drawback), I retain that the combo 'small phone + cycling GPS' works very well, if you don't need a large phone otherwise.

Comment: Good point on maintaining waterproofing.  I successfully repaired a cheap waterproof Android once, but the second repair (screen replacement) leaked slightly and it became irritating to keep it safe.  But that wasn't what finished it off

Comment: Hi Renaud, have you found direct sun exposure to be a problem in practice? In my experience, when you're riding, even in direct sunlight and 35°C heat the phone is more than sufficiently cooled by the wind, and when you stop, you take it with you. ••• I too found that an iPhone 12 or 13 is too large to put on the bike handlebar's out-front mount that I had. Looking for a new mount now... and in general thinking of downgrading to the iPhone 13 Mini, not only for cycling but for general ergonomic reasons. But I'm pretty sure that I'll get at least 6 hours of biking even on the Mini.

Comment: @ttarchala No long term experience, as I only use my phone for navigation when biking in cities (for the long rides, I had a Garmin before the Wahoo). Heat is known to accelerate the wear of batteries, but in which extend depends on too many factors (but one thing is sure, if the battery of the phone is small to start with, you'll feel the effect of an aging battery much faster). It's more a concern than a reason to not use the phone on the handle bar.

Answer (score 3):

I use both - I have a $4 "cycle computer" attached to the bars of one bike.  Its sole purpose is to display my current speed, and the clock.  Those are literally the only two functions I care about.   Its not even pretend-waterproof, but has survived 6 months.   Being so cheap, the battery life is abysmal, so its going to get replaced with a low-end $20 Cateye.

The cheap cyclecomputer stays on the bike at all times.  I don't even bother unclipping it when in a shop.

On the same rides, my fancyphone is tucked safely into my bag or jersey pocket.  Its job is to run Strava and I don't touch it during the ride.   Sometimes I ride with a HRM, but that info is logged by the phone, and I don't use it for training.

Would I use an expensive Garmin or Wahoo head unit?  Definitely, if I owned one.  But they're ridiculously expensive, easily costing 3-5x as much as my bike, so I couldn't justify buying one while other things demand payment first.

Comment: I didn't mention the cheap cyclocomputer as an option, because the acknowledged need for GPS and navigation on the bike is sort of a prerequisite to asking the question... what do you use as a GPS/navigation/turn-by-turn/attraction discovery solution then?

Comment: @ttarchala I plan my route before going, and learn the significant points/turns.  Generally speaking I know my way around my city and the adjoining province.  On the off chance I get really lost then I'd stop and use the phone, but absolutely not while riding.

Comment: @ttarchala if this answer misses the point of the question, let me know and I'll simply remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still think it adds to the overall information contents by reminding everybody about the simple cyclocomputer option. In fact, it made my think that if I had one in addition to my smartphone mount, this could perhaps help save some battery because I wouldn't have to wake up the phone as often to check the time/speed/distance.

Comment: @Criggie: I have no idea how long a battery in a $20 CatEye holds - mine is still on the original battery after two years and 3500 km...

Comment: Minor update - I have acquired small drops of water inside the computer's display.  It was going to happen eventually.

Answer (score 3):

IP67/68 resistant phones do exist, but regular phones offer a much larger choice (especially if you exclude the non-rugged IP67 phones which are not quite comparable to bike GPS in terms of protection). If you want to use your phone as a bike GPS, you will be limited to those sturdy phones. And such phones themselves result from a compromise between the sound / microphone quality (which require more holes and/or larger holes) and the IP rating (which ideally requires to have no holes at all).

Bigger weight of the phone is also a significant disadvantage which is not completely countered by "you still have to have it with you". Having extra 200 grams in the backpack is rather insignificant, while having extra 100 grams (200 grams phone instead of 100 grams bike GPS) mounted on the handlebars does make a difference: the amount of shaking you can take is reduced by two, assuming the same mount quality.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you make a distinction between the IP6x resistant phones and "regular phones" - don't most flagship phones nowadays feature IP67 or IP68 resistance? And there are a lot of people already using the "regular phones" as a bike GPS with success?

Comment: @ttarchala Most phones I see around have an audio jack, and it's never sealed, so if these phones have an IP67 rating, it's only on paper.

Comment: The audio jack (as well as USB) is actually sealed: this is not too difficult to do. In any case, IP67 is quite sufficient for riding in the rain. However, I agree that selection of such phones is rather limited in mid-range (which to me make most sense: I wouldn't like to to mount a "flagship phone" (as @ttarchala implied) on the handlebars, esp. without a full protective case - which defeats the point of having IP67).

Comment: My IP68-rated phone uses rubber bungs for the USB and headphone sockets, for example.  This means it ends up with not-quite-standard connectors, but it works well. That's a cheap phone.  My previous waterproof (can't recall IP rating) phone was a rather nice Sony, but the seals were fiddly.  It did have the ability to charge without breaking the seals though, using a magnetic 2-pin connector.  The newer version was just too expensive though

Comment: @ChrisH I didn't mean it was impossible to seal the audio jack (otherwise the phone wouldn't get the rating), just that the seals tend to be not used / lost / broken. It doesn't have to be the case of course.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev so far they seem pretty robust on my Blackview (moulded rubber, firmly tethered).  The cap for the USB on my Sony wasn't so good and I replaced it a couple of times.  Some (Samsung I think) use audio sockets that are sealed on the inside so there's no need for a bung.  This doesn't work so well for USB

Answer (score 3):

Many answers mention battery life as an advantage to dedicated cycling GPS units. However, this issue hasn’t been explicitly addressed yet: on phones, the screen is a major drain on battery life. Phone screens are usually on standby. Cycling computers use much simpler screens with lower power consumption. Thus, if you value being able to see your statistics or your mapping software without having to take an extra action, the cycling computer is clearly superior. This isn’t critical functionality for all users, however! It depends on the use case. A casual cyclist may have more than sufficient power on their phone, and they might only occasionally check a map.

People have mentioned durability of the phone in a crash as a concern. Dedicated phone mounts with cases, e.g. Quadlock, can offset this concern. Remember that most cyclists don’t crash often, and of the times we do crash, a phone in a hard case that’s secured to the bars may not take damage. This does depend on having a secure mount, and my understanding is that Quadlock is pretty secure. I have no personal experience with them. I believe that they have at least a few credible competitors, but I can’t remember which ones.

Comment: Hi Weiwen, good point about the stats, but it's generally self-regulating: if you pay a lot of attention to the stats, for example to keep your power or heart rate within a defined band, you're probably doing a high intensity or interval training, so you can keep the screen on – the ride will be relatively short. And on a longer ride, you certainly don't need to look at the screen to check your power every 10 seconds etc. Actually the bigger problem I found as a competitive rider is the lack of apps displaying comprehensive stats. The best app I found is Wahoo but if you know any better...

Answer (score 3):

I do use an iPhone rather than a dedicated head unit, but I think I can speak to some of the drawbacks (and non-drawbacks) of using a phone.

- Mounting options: It is possible to mount your phone like a bike computer, but its weight and moment of inertia on the mount are too much for some mounts; it also may not fit between the stem and some out-front mounts. In short, your options are a little more restricted.
- Data displays: On a smartphone, you're limited to the data fields that the author of the app your using has chosen to make available (which can be extensive, but are not extensible, AFAICT). With higher-end Garmins, you can add new data fields that can be calculated from your existing data sources, and out of the box, Garmins have some interesting displays, like detailed hill gradients, that I haven't seen in a phone app.
- Compatibility: All modern phones support BTLE, all modern head units support this and ANT+. Most modern accessories support both. There are BTLE/ANT+ gateways available, but if you've got ANT+-only accessories, there could be more fiddling. The coin cell powering my chest strap runs for about one year.
- Always-on display. This is possible with a phone, but as mentioned, it runs the battery down a lot faster.
- Aesthetics: Some people think that having a big phone hanging off the front of the bars looks dumb. That's a matter of taste.

Smartphones used as bike computers have some advantages, or work better when not used as a direct replacement.

- Better navigation: You've got a big map, and there are cycling apps (RideWithGPS) that can speak turn-by-turn directions; head units will just beep at you to notify that there's a turn coming up, and you need to read the screen. Those spoken directions can be a big advantage when following a new route. Some people miss those beeps.
- Spoken stats: Instead of keeping the screen on all the time, you can have the app speak your stats at regular intervals. This isn't appropriate for all situations (intervals), and can be downright annoying in some (out-of-zone warnings), but it is a way the phone is different, not necessarily worse.
- Simplicity: There's a learning curve with any new gadget, and a need to keep it up to date. If you've got a smartphone anyhow, you can avoid that.

With the screen mostly off, a smartphone has plenty of battery life: I've done 12-hour rides with mine without recharging. Most modern smartphones are waterproof, so that's not a big consideration, although I've found that you can't charge an iPhone when the charging port is wet. Crashworthiness might be a reasonable concern, but I keep mine in a robust case, between a pair of aerobars, on a lanyard, so it probably isn't going to take any hard hits.

Comment: Cellular coverage seems to have the most impact on battery life.  When in poor coverage (as we a wont to do when out for long scenic rides)  then the phone's transmitter has to "yell harder" to talk to a base station which uses more power.  I've had battery completely flat after 90 minutes, where my normal 1h commute only uses 20%.   USB power banks help but the plugs are always fragile, on phone mostly.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I went on a six hours ride in a hilly, forested area (where GPS lost its signal), and there was a distinct lack of phone coverage (for an hour or so).
Surprisingly (or not), the Strava application recorded a ONE WEEK trip (which the Strava site wouldn't accept for uploading).
Also, I've had another ride where the GPS "registered" the ride 200 meters away from the road (part of it on a 70% incline :), and part of it through houses and gardens ) and a 140 km/h maximum speed (compared to the 60 km/h max or so recorded by the $20 bike computer).
Now the speed sensors might be "slaved" to the mobile phone and be used by Strava to improve "reckoning", but usually mobile phone plus GPS application means no wheel speed sensors, no pedaling rate sensors, ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your experiences might be Strava-specific. I use Strava myself, but only as a background recording app, because I also found it unreliable in similar ways (e.g. crossing a river on a 100-meter tall bridge, Strava recorded a 100m downhill then 100m uphill...)  The best apps for general cycling I know are Komoot and RideWithGPS.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here but GPS is GPS irrelevant of the fact if it's on a dedicated bike computer or a phone. If your in an area where GPS is likely to drop out it will regardless. Personally I use my watch to track GPS data and a phone mounted on handlebars to give me distance and speed (GPS) do I need to use both? Only because it's very hard to see everything on the watch when riding.

Comment: @DanK Not all GPS receivers are equal. My phone's GPS is terrible; my bike computer's GPS works perfectly in exactly the same places.

Comment: @DanK Honestly no, all comes down to the type of GPS antenna in the device, quality of antenna, placement of antenna etc. mostly. A cheap patch antenna vs an expensive patch antenna, whilst from the outside looking basically identical, can be a night and day comparison in my experience.

Comment: @Dan, we don't usually realise how incredibly weak GPS signal is (<-130 dBm); its by far the weakest useful radio signal in common use. Consequently, the demands to the antenna and processing quality are very high. This by itself doesn't 'prove' the point, but in practice a dedicated GPS device nearly always wins. Another point is that practically all phone GPSes are [A-GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS). While this improves things in some circumstances, in practice they are so reliant on this 'assistance' that they often refuse to acquire satellites without the data/phone...

Comment: ...network, especially if they weren't connected for some time and/or moved - which is exactly where GPS is needed most. _All_ the phones I owned experienced multi-minute acquisition delays (or sometimes complete failures) after moving to another country where I didn't have data roaming - which is a very common situation. Yet my dedicated Garmin never takes more than 40 seconds to start.

Comment: @ttarchala, evidently, the Strava app doesn't trust the GPS-reported elevation (which is indeed the least accurate) and uses a topo map for elevations. Which doesn't know about bridges or tunnels. I'm surprised though this is a 'normal' behaviour (I don't use Strava); in RideWithGPS you can replace elevations with topo as an option later if you don't like the recorded ones - which is exactly as it should be.

Comment: @Zeus I've had little experience with cheap Android phones, I ride with an iPhone and even in a wooded ravine with no GSM signal it rarely takes it more than 30-60 seconds to get a GPS fix. Normally it's instanteneous, a few seconds at most. Never had a failure in a foreign country either. (Please don't take this as an invitation to a iPhone/Android holy war, just sharing my experiences)

Comment: @Zeus So the phone has to download the almanac if it hasn't been used in a while.  Not an issue if you actually use it.  I've been using (Android) phone GPSs offline for over 10 years, probably 10 models from 5 brands, cheap to high-end and **not once** has the phone failed to get a fix with no mobile data and a clear view of the sky. AGPS is only ever a speedup except for a few very rare obsolete phones with L1-only receivers.

Comment: @ChrisH, well, my experience is different, despite a similar statistics. At some point, I had a phone (a flagship HTC model) which I used only as a PDA (computer). It was permanently in flight mode, and I enabled GPS only when I needed it: exactly the way I would use a standalone GPS. Well, it failed to get a fix many times, and taking 5+ min to get initial fix was the norm.

Answer (score 2):

Once we had scientific surveys (in the middle of the desert) with the teams using mobile phones (with specialized software) and also Garmin devices (for positioning). Since then I remember that navigation devices were easily readable in very direct and bright sunlight, when nothing was visible on the phone without raising it close to the eyes and covering with hand from the sun.

Probably some different technology is used for displays that work in the direct sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers cover other issues very well, and the question kind of mentions this, but I think it's still a valid concern.

I have an iPhone 7 Plus - so not the newest smartphone in the world, but still fairly new. With the screen turned on, when exposed to sunlight, it can heat up a lot. This can affect performance and I don't think is without effect on the lifetime of the battery at least. Where I live, temperatures can sometimes exceed 45 degrees Celsius - and frequently exceed 30, and having the phone exposed to sunlight for hours at a time in these conditions is a no go. My Garmin, on the other hand, never really feels like it's overheating.

And, on top of that, it's got better GPS, better battery life, independent battery so it dying won't make me unable to make calls, is more handy and smaller, has a dedicated mount, integrates well with a whole bunch of sensors and so on and so forth...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Lasooch. I haven't ridden in recent years beyond temperatures in the 35-37 range, and indeed the phone can get hot - unless you are riding, when it's cooled by the wind. But normally when you stop, you take the phone with you so it's not a problem. Did you find the phone getting uncomfortably hot _while riding_ ?

Comment: @ttarchala to be honest, no - I never actually tried putting it up on the handlebars and keeping the screen on. It does get very hot in the car though, even with the AC running, if the screen is on and it's exposed to sunlight. Wind cooling vs much lower temperature - a bit apples to oranges, but that's the best I've got ;)

Comment: "cooled by the wind" stops working for me when I start climbing. You may be faster than I am! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another good reason, maybe not fully bike related to use a phone instead of a bike computer, is that you can take pictures with your phone.

I used to use the quadlock mount with my phone, and it was very easy to remove the phone to take a quick picture.

Now, because I'm using a garmin device my phone is in my bag and if I need/want to take a picture, I have to stop, remove my bag, pick my phone, take a picture and reverse all that.

Even if my phone is in one of the pocket in my bike jersey, it is not as easy as picking it up from the mount.

Comment: You find it easier to remove your phone from a secure handlebar mount than to simply take it out of your pocket? Does not compute. Also, this doesn't answer the question. The question is asking why one would use a bike computer instead of the phone, and you're explaining why you would use a phone instead of a bike computer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, not only it's super easy to disengage the phone from the mount, but on the Topeak mount, it takes literally three seconds to flip the phone to a vertical landscape position and start recording video, hands-free, while riding. The video will be shaky but certainly usable e.g. in case of a dispute about a traffic incident.     ... And hey, weren't we supposed to "stop trying to engage every answerer in lengthy discussions about every single thing they say"?

Comment: @ttarchala I'm not trying to engage in discussions. I'm trying to get Max to justify a claim made in their post, and to point out that the post doesn't actually answer the question. Your comment, in contrast, is mostly about proposing a new non-answer (a mounted phone can be used to shoot video, which is a reason _not_ to use a dedicated GPS unit) and about arguing with me. Please stop.